# Protractor: How to store number text from div element

Tags: arrays, random, protractor, gettext

I'm using Protractor and Angular page. On the page there are each time displayed random 5 selected numbers out of 50 available. How can I store text for each of those 5 numbers into one variable? All selected numbers have one attribute and its value in common.

HTML:

```
<div class="basic-number-selected" ...</div>
```

Page object file:

```
this.selectedNumbers = element.all(by.css('div.basic-number-selected'));
```

Do any of you have an idea how can I store text of each selected number?

I've tried with `each`, but without any success:

```
var numbers = [];

page.selectedNumbers.getText().each(function(num) {
    numbers.push(num);
});

console.log("Selected numbers: " + numbers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 page.selectedNumbers.getText().then(function(numbers) {
            browser.executeScript(
                function(array){
                    return JSON.stringify(array);
                },numbers).then(function(str){
                console.log(str);
            });
        });
```